# Android Rect.intersects

Tags: java, android, collision, rect

I'm trying to implement a rect collision if statement using the androind rect class, but I can't seem to get it to work, well it does work but the return statement is never true, here is my if statement

```
if(Rect.intersects(balls.get(j).topSide, levelBlocks.blocks.get(i).rect))
    {
        Log.d("Check", "Hit");
    }
```

Here is the information I have printed which does show there should be a collision

```
06-09 18:17:50.842: D/Check(6016): Bloc1X:192, Y:64, W:32, H:32
06-09 18:17:50.862: D/Check(6016): Ball X:199, Y:92, W:18, H:6
```

here is a picture with the locations pointed, the image resolution is the same as the application canvas [image]

If anyone can help me out that would be great :).

Here is some more code

```
if(i == 2)
                    {
                        Log.d("Check", "Ball X:"+ balls.get(j).topSide.left+",Y:"+ balls.get(j).topSide.top+", W:"+ balls.get(j).topSide.right+", H:"+balls.get(j).topSide.bottom);
                        Log.d("Check", "Bloc1X:"+ levelBlocks.blocks.get(i).rect.left+", Y:"+ levelBlocks.blocks.get(i).rect.top+", W:"+ levelBlocks.blocks.get(i).rect.right+", H:"+levelBlocks.blocks.get(i).rect.bottom);
                    }
                    if(Rect.intersects(balls.get(j).topSide, levelBlocks.blocks.get(i).rect))
                    {
                        Log.d("Check", "hit");
                    }
```

Comment: First of all ensure that the values shown in the log are really those given as parameters to `Rect.intersects()`

Comment: and how would i show those? also those logs are taken from the variables passed into the intersects

Comment: Just before the `if` assign the parameters to local variables. You can then log them or use a debugger to put a breakpoint and inspect the values

Comment: Yea i did that, and the results at top are the ones i get. I have checked again and yep, all of the rects in my ball is 0,0,0,0 so it is checking against nothing...why on earth is that heppening

Comment: could you show a little more of your code? maybe just before the 'if' statement and the logging stuff. also, are both of the objects you check for intersection pure rectangles or is one an object that extends rectangle?

Comment: The `right` value of a Rectangle means `left + width`, similar for `bottom`

Comment: This piece of code here is in the balls update method leftSide.left = xPos;
  leftSide.top = (yPos + 2);
  leftSide.right = 6;
  leftSide.bottom = (height - 4);

Comment: wait, do you have a ball class that extends rectangle?

Comment: nope, does it need to? :(

Comment: no. however, the rectangle.right value is supposed to be left + width. and the rectangle.bottom value is top + height. if you set these to 6 and height - 4, you're messing everything up with the intersection check or logging.

Comment: oohh so what should i put there instead?

Comment: if you want to log the height and width, just use rect.getHeight() and rect.getWidth(). then, see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what some of the code you have is for like ".topSide".

But if you take a look at the documentation for rectangles you can just pass the two rectangles to the insersects() method and it'll return true or false:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersects(android.graphics.Rect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersects%28android.graphics.Rect), android.graphics.Rect)

I am of course assuming both of your entities are of type Rect. If not then this isn't going to work.